# AWK prints column depends on header with delimiter comma

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to print columns with the specified column names. But I found when the delimiter is ",", my code cannot split the line. It would print the whole line. Could you help me to figure out this issue?

My input file has 3 columns splited by comma:

```
AWS_path,path
aws_test1,11111
aws_test2,22222
```

My code:

```
input=$1
awk -F "," 'NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
        print $i
        print f[$i]
    }
} NR>1 { print $(f["AWS_path"]), $(f["path"])}' $input
```

The result shows the AWS_path and the path. I think it should be:

```
aws_test1 11111
aws_test2 22222
```

But indeed it outputs as below, its path column includes the whole line rather than only 2nd column.

```
aws_test1,11111 aws_test1,11111
aws_test2,22222 aws_test2,22222
```

I have tried many ways. But I cannot fix it. Could do please help me?

Comment: your code works for me

Comment: Yeah, it works. I recommend to use a readable example, like: `foo_aws_path,foo_variant_type,foo_path`

Comment: @kvantour,@hek2mgl I updated my example to be more readable. Could you try it again?

Comment: If you're on windows, your data file might be UTF-16, where your code's ... basically any 8-bit ascii-based set, UTF-8, ISO-Latin-1, ASCII, all the same.  The readin would show the UTF-16 header, with the nulls, but that wouldn't match the coding in your file.  Try piping your output through `cat -A` or a full-on hex dumper to see if that's it.  Or just `file input.txt` and see what it says about the code page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file has Windows line-endings ie.`\r\n` instead of just `\n`, therefore your code has `"path"` but the file has `path\r` and no match. Use `dos2unix file` or similar:

```
$ awk -f program.awk file    # testing with \r\n endings
AWS_path
1
path
2
aws_test1 aws_test1,11111
aws_test2 aws_test2,22222
$ dos2unix file              # convert to \n
$ awk -f program.awk file    # testing with \n endings
AWS_path
1
path
2
aws_test1 11111
aws_test2 22222
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think the `\r\n` should be the issue. Cause when I create the example on Linux, the code works. But when I tried the dos2unix. It still returns the whole line. crying...

Comment: Very nice catch

Comment: That is weird .